# Running a Phoenix application release with exrm crashes

Tags: release, elixir, phoenix-framework, exrm

I am trying to create a release of a stock `Phoenix` application (based on Elixir and Erlang) using `exrm`.

The first release for the `dev` mix environment is created fine, but crashes when run using `./rel/my_app/bin/my_app console`. This happens running Ubuntu 14.04 inside a Vagrant/Virtual Box virtual machine.

On my Mac, the same setup runs fine. Unfortunately, I need to build the release on a machine with the same architecture as the target server, which will run Ubuntu.

You can find the application here: https://github.com/mavenastic/my_app. It includes the steps taken to install dependencies and create the project on the VM (see `STEPS.md`) as well as a [Erlang crash dump](https://github.com/mavenastic/my_app/blob/master/rel/my_app/erl_crash.dump).

Here is the error I get from attempting to run the console:

```
{"Kernel pid terminated",application_controller,"{application_start_failure,my_app,{{shutdown,{failed_to_start_child,'Elixir.MyApp.Endpoint',{shutdown,{failed_to_start_child,'Elixir.Phoenix.CodeReloader.Server',{undef,[{'Elixir.Mix.Project',config,[],[]},{'Elixir.Phoenix.CodeReloader.Server',init,1,[{file,\"lib/phoenix/code_reloader/server.ex\"},{line,29}]},{gen_server,init_it,6,[{file,\"gen_server.erl\"},{line,328}]},{proc_lib,init_p_do_apply,3,[{file,\"proc_lib.erl\"},{line,240}]}]}}}}},{'Elixir.MyApp',start,[normal,[]]}}}"}
```

**EDIT:**

I tried to create a release for the production environment as well with `MIX_ENV=prod mix release`. The release is successfully generated and `MIX_ENV=prod PORT=8889 ./rel/my_app/bin/my_app console` runs fine. However, I cannot ping the server nor run a remote console once it starts, so it seems something is still missing for the application to run properly.

```
$ MIX_ENV=prod PORT=8889 ./rel/my_app/bin/my_app start
$ MIX_ENV=prod PORT=8889 ./rel/my_app/bin/my_app ping

=INFO REPORT==== 24-Oct-2015::10:28:25 ===
Protocol: "inet_tcp": register/listen error: econnrefused
escript: exception error: no match of right hand side value
                 {error,
                     {{shutdown,
                          {failed_to_start_child,net_kernel,
                              {'EXIT',nodistribution}}},
                      {child,undefined,net_sup_dynamic,
                          {erl_distribution,start_link,
                              [['my_app_maint_2551@127.0.0.1',longnames]]},
                          permanent,1000,supervisor,
                          [erl_distribution]}}}

$ ps aux | grep my_app
vagrant   2572  0.0  0.0   7532    96 ?        S    10:28   0:00 /vagrant/my_app/rel/my_app/erts-7.1/bin/epmd -daemon
vagrant   2575  0.0  0.2   9448  2256 pts/0    S+   10:28   0:00 grep --color=auto my_app

$ MIX_ENV=prod PORT=8889 ./rel/my_app/bin/my_app remote_console
$
```

Also, from what I gathered, I should be able to create a release for the `dev` or any other environment as well. So the missing piece might affect both environments.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per @bitwalker suggestion, using the `master` branch of `exrm` fixed the issue.

Answer (score 2):

To me it looks like the problem is that you're creating the release in your `dev` environment (instead of the `prod` env).

This part:

```
{undef,[{'Elixir.Mix.Project',config,[],[]}
```

of the (terribly and awesomely à la Erlang) error message basically says that `Mix.Project.config/0` is undefined. Mix is not included in releases but I'm guessing Phoenix uses it in its code reloader, which you usually don't run in production.

Try generating the release with `MIX_ENV=prod` and see if it works.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @whatyouhide. From what I understand, I should be able to create a release for the `dev` environment, see [here](http://hashnuke.com/2015/07/19/convenience-hacks-for-using-exrm-with-phoenix-apps.html). I will try to create a release for the `prod` one and let you know the results.

Answer (score 1):

I put this in the issue tracker, but just for posterity here as well:

You need to add `server: true` to your `prod.exs` under the config for `MyApp.Endpoint`. This is how Phoenix starts itself within a release.

With Phoenix, I would recommend always using `MIX_ENV=prod` for releases, `MIX_ENV=dev` has a lot of development specific features (such as code reloading), that either won't work within a release, or won't work as expected.

If you are getting config errors, it's probably because you are missing some required Phoenix configuration in your environment-specific file. You can test this by running `MIX_ENV=prod mix compile` to see if it compiles successfully. You can also build your release with `--verbosity=verbose` to get detailed output for tracing down problems.

The reason why you couldn't ping or console to the release is because it failed on startup.

Comment: Thanks @bitwalker. Adding `server: true` unfortunately does not solve the problem. It might be something obvious I am missing. I updated the issue [on Github](https://github.com/bitwalker/exrm/issues/218), will update this post when a solution is found.

Comment: Any idea why this is not set by default?

Answer (score 1):

@bitwalker is correct, in your `config/prod.exs` file you must add `server: true` a la http://www.phoenixframework.org/v0.13.1/docs/advanced-deployment.

I cloned your project and generated a `dev` release and am getting the same failure you are.  I have gotten this same failure on many of my personal projects with the `dev` build.  However, the `prod` build always still works.

Thus, after putting in place a `config/prod.secret.exs` with the correct information in it and adding the `server: true` to my `config/prod.exs` file, I am able to generate a prod release and execute `console`, `start` and `ping` successfully. I suspect the hot code reloader could be the culprit in the `dev` build but have no proof excluding it being present in the error and definitely something that is different about `dev` vs `prod`.

BTW, when starting the application, you only need to specify the `PORT`, not `MIX_ENV` as this is a release and mix is not in play:

`PORT=4000 bin/my_app start`

My advice is to skip the `dev` build and just use a `staging` and `prod` build.  If you do not have a `staging` server, you can deploy the `staging` release to a local machine a la https://exrm.readme.io/docs/deployment.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed info @jason-harrelson. In my latest tests, I was using the `prod` environment only so I am not sure why it was still failing. Using the `master` branch of `exrm` fixed the issue.